# When $ax+b$ is irreducible in an Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$\text{Theorem: In an Integral Domain} \ R[x]$

$$\text{If}\ a \in U(R)\implies ax+b\ \text{is Irreducible in}\ R[x].$$

It's easy to prove it.

*My question: Is the **converse** of this theorem right?*

Example: Let be $f(x)=3x+2\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. The element $$3\not \in U(\mathbb{Z})=\{+1,-1\} \kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies f(x)\ \text{is NOT Irreducible in}\ \mathbb{Z}[x].$$

*My answer:*

1st WAY: The only factorizations in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is $f(x)=1(3x+2)$ and $f(x)=(-1)(-3x-2)$ and that means that $f(x)$ is irreducile in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

2nd WAY: $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]\iff f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (because $f(x)$ is primitive).

*Are all these things correct?*

Comment: By $U(R)$, do you mean the units of $R$?

Comment: Yes, my friend.

Comment: Any more answers?

Comment: @user26857 Thank you. But is $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle 3x+2  \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/ \langle 3  \rangle$ ?

Comment: @Chris No; but the quotient *is* a domain, which still shows that what you said in your question is correct.